# Swift Charts how to get chartValue using mouse hover instead of mouse click in MacOS

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst

I use [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) framework to draw charts in MacOS application. I have `CombinedChartView` with `candleData`. When I click by mouse a candle, `chartValueSelected` executed and I can receive information about selected candle. I need to do the same using `UIHoverGestureRecognizer` instead of mouse click. How to get information about a `chartValue` that mouse is hover?

Comment: Is this a Catalyst app, otherwise there is no UIHoverGestureRecognizer?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes Catalyst app and I already implemented UIHoverGestureRecognizer. I don't know hot to pass is to CombinedChartView

Answer (score 0):

The only one way I found is to add `UIHoverGestureRecognizer` to `BarLineChartViewBase.swift`